# Microsoft Access 2007 Connection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I wrote a program that connected to a Microsoft Access 2000/2003 mdb file and accesses the data. It works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a way to connect to Access 2007? If I change my connection string, will my program work with access 2007 or is it more complicated then that? And if it will work, can someone provide an example of an Access 2007 database?

Comment: I'm curious: did you try this before you posted? Do you not have Access 2007, so you can't try it out? Where's this question coming from?

Answer (score 6):

You will need to download the [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en) (doesn't require Access 2007 installed). Then changing the connection string to point to the Access 2007 database should be sufficient.

Useful site: [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very poorly worded. Access 2007 offers two different file format, the traditional MDB format, and the ACCDB format. If you use MDB format, then you don't need any additional drivers, as it's the same format in 2007 as in previous versions (and might be compatible back to Access 2000, since that's the default format for all versions from Access 2000 to 2003). You need the additional data connectivity components if you choose the ACCDB format. There is little reason to do so, as most of the new features of ACCDB are there in order to be compatible with Sharepoint.